# Magento bundle product Quantity box for checkbox

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have created one bundle product containing many bundle items. SO I am adding that bundle items to cart using check box. But how to add quantity box for bundle items using check box to select. So that, I can add many items for that checked bundle item ?

Comment: Why not using dropdown/radio button?

Comment: because I want to create my own box. Like where I can put my products to that box(means like container). for e.g Cakes. Package of 6 cup-cakes. So for that user can select their product and add to the "Own box". He will be able to add single product multiple times. so how to do that? if you are clear with what I explained then please let me know about your views. And suggest me the solution to accomplish this task. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create bundle products and make a group of those products.

Now on a page you display on these grouped product.

This will be a simpler approach else you need to come with a complex module to handle your feature request